# My ubuntu got pwned, what to do to prevent/detect it in the future

Tags: ubuntu

My system got hacked, and I'm reinstalling the system while unplugged from internet.

I read somewhere to save some file (such as ps) somewhere,
so I can check if those files were modified when I suspect being compromised again.

I can't remember which files to save, nor the post.

What files should I save so that I get to know something is happening fast next time.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having a webserver running ?? if so check which directories have write and execute enabled for public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking of **Intrusion Detection Systems**, aka IDS.

A common choice on Ubuntu is [`tripwire`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-tripwire-to-detect-server-intrusions-on-an-ubuntu-vps).